# how to load content from external php jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, this, href

I'm stupid, sorry. But I really don't get it working!
I would love to have the content beeing loaded from an external php file.

e.g. myfeed.php .

the content is wrapped in a class called "myfeed".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$("#bestseller a").click(function(){

    var post_id = $(this).attr("rel")
    $(".featureline").html("loading...");
    $(".featureline").load(jQuery(this).attr("href") + " .myfeed")
    return false;
});
```

});

could anybody please tell me how to modify this code above to get it working? The Ajax loading works - but I don't get the external file loaded.

Many thanks!
AD

Comment: You might be better off using an id rather that a class to load the contents of an element, look under the heading 'script execution' in the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".featureline").load(FileURL);
```

`FileURL` should be path to your file, eg. `myfeed.php`.

Answer (score 1):

The `+ " .myfeed")` looks out of place in this line:

```
  $(".featureline").load(jQuery(this).attr("href") + " .myfeed")
```

Remove it and your query will work.

```
$(".featureline").load(jQuery(this).attr("href"));
```